# OSX Permanently Set PYTHONPATH

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, osx-mountain-lion, pythonpath

I have a problem where my PYTHONPATH variable always has a blank value. I can fix it temporarily like this:
`export PYTHONPATH=$(python -c 'import sys;print ":".join(sys.path)')`
but is there a more permanent way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put that line in your `~/.bash_profile` file, at which point it is run each time a new terminal is opened. (See [here](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/6.3/postlfs/profile.html) for more about this file).

Answer (score 1):

1. put the path setting in /etc/profile, it will impact to all users.
2. put the path in your home directory ~/.profile, ~/.bashrc, ~/kshrc (depand on your shell).